# list box in html5 doesn't change

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I want to change the size of list box in html5, I've been trying many solutions from answers to such issue, but none works !! the list box does not change

Note: I'me using Cordova to create a cross-platform mobile app
[image: list box]
as you see in the picture the list box is like the screen width and i want to change it

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #social_icons {
            /*padding: .5em;*/
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 2.7;
            -webkit-columns: 150px 2;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        .topmenu li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #footer {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 10;
            height: 3em;
            margin-top: -3em;
        }
        #wgmstr {
    max-width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: 30px !important;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>menu</h1>
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:4400/homePageArabic.html" data-icon="back"> back</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear"></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="jan">Jan</option>
                    <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                    <option value="march">March</option>
                    <option value="april">April</option>
                    <option value="may">May</option>
                    <option value="june">June</option>
                    <option value="july">July</option>
                    <option value="august">Aug</option>
                    <option value="sep">Sep</option>
                    <option value="oct">Oct</option>
                    <option value="nov">Nov</option>
                    <option value="dec">Dec</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="footer" data-role="footer" style="text-align:center">
                <h1></h1>


                <div id="social_icons">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300106_instagram.png" align="middle"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300135_facebook.png" align="middle"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479310570_youtube.png" align="middle"></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300112_twitter.png" align="middle"></a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed what you mean. The dropdown menu was the width of the page.

When I started I also noticed that the footer was on top of drop-down list, so I added additional CSS to push it to the bottom, center the social icons and added the `<h1></h1>` below the social icons.

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/7sozqpnv/2/), for you to review.

I added the following CSS to adjust the size of the drop-down box, which as of now with the line I added only take up 50% of the page, but you can adjust to the size of your liking.

Let me know if that helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#pageone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.ui-content {
  width: 50%; /* adjust drop-down size here to whatever size you would like. */
}

#social_icon {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#social_icons a {
          left: auto;
          right: auto;
          display: inline;
          border: none;
          text-decoration: none;
          padding-right: 20px;
      }

      .topmenu li {
          display: inline-block;
      }

      /* added code to push footer to bottom. */
      #footer {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          height: 60px;
          width:100%;
          text-align: center;
      }

      #footer p {
        clear: both;
        color: black;
        opacity: 0.3;
      }
      #wgmstr {
  max-width: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>menu</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://localhost:4400/homePageArabic.html" data-icon="back"> back</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
          <option value="jan">Jan</option>
          <option value="feb">Feb</option>
          <option value="march">March</option>
          <option value="april">April</option>
          <option value="may">May</option>
          <option value="june">June</option>
          <option value="july">July</option>
          <option value="august">Aug</option>
          <option value="sep">Sep</option>
          <option value="oct">Oct</option>
          <option value="nov">Nov</option>
          <option value="dec">Dec</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
        <div id="social_icons">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300106_instagram.png" align="middle"></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300135_facebook.png" align="middle"></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479310570_youtube.png" align="middle"></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/1479300112_twitter.png" align="middle"></a>
        </div>

        <p>&copy; 2016</p>
      </div>
   </div>
```